# Is it possible to sandbox JavaScript in an IFrame where the IFrame content is running under the same domain?

Tags: javascript, iframe

We have an application that reconstructs external web sites in an Iframe from within our domain so we can use tools that run in the browser to inspect the external website. This is an unavoidable requirement since we need to gather information about the external page using JavaScript. If the page were not reconstructed from within our domain, we would run into cross site scripting issues.

The problem is that the scripts on some pages redirect out of the iframe, which stops our tool from working.

My query is whether there is a way to allow the scripts to run within the iframe, but not to affect the page that contains the iFrame?

Hope that makes sense - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I do not thinks so.

If the Iframe is loaded from the same domain any script will have full access to the page.

The redirect out of the page you refere to is the page protection from Hijacking where another site tries to use the page contents.

By ridirecting out of an iframe they avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a separate window (window.open) to load the reconstructed external sites instead of an iframe. As long as they are at the same domain, they'll still be able to communicate, but the child window won't be likely to mess with your main window.

Alternatively, your outer window can do nothing, and be at a different (sub)domain from your control window. Your control window is an iframe in your outer window, and the reconstructed external site is another iframe sharing the same domain as your control frame. Now if your 'external' iframe tries to do something with window.top (besides navigate) it will fail because of the cross-domain policy, but your control iframe will share the same domain as your 'external' iframe, so you can inspect and manipulate it.

If you use the second approach, frames will still be able to navigate the top window. You can prevent it by adding something like this in the top window:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){return '';};
```

Now you'll be prompted with a dialog box if anything tries to navigate the page, and you can abort navigation. This will probably fix your current approach by itself, but it may be best to have the top window at a separate domain in case the external site tries to do anything unexpected with it.